# AS3 Security.showSettings() not always shows dialog in FF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I call `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY)` in my AS3 script and it always shows dialog in Chrome, but in Firefox it only works when I place my `file.swf` directly on the html page. Nothing happens when I insert it dynamically via `swfobject.js(v2.2)` and after some time try to open security panel.

Lately this worked fine in both browsers. Is there some trick?

Comment: does it work if embedded with `<object>`/`<embed>` written manually?

Comment: Yes, it works in this case. But in my production version I don't control the host page and can't embed it till my js-application is loaded.